# Get `Cannot read property 'type' of null` using Angular2 AoT ngc compiler with RC5

Tags: angular

Update to Angular2 2.0.0-rc.5, run in browser without any warning, but when try AOT compile with `ngc -p` command, get the flowing error:

[image]

Here is my project https://github.com/beginor/learning-angular2

Comment: This is a bug in ngc. Created the following bug to track this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12020

Answer (score 5):

Do not use default exports in your code:

```
// somefile.ts
export default function (...) {
    ...
}
...
// some-other-file.ts
import whatevar from './somefile';
```

use explicit names instead

```
// somefile.ts
export function whatevar(...) {
    ...
}
...
// some-other-file.ts
import { whatevar } from './somefile';
```

AOT is incompatible with default exports (among other things).
But unlike other incompatibilities, this one generates the most cryptic error message ever.

Comment: You have saved me many hours of my life! I was able to solve this error message: `ngc: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined ... @angular\tsc-wrapped\src\collector.js:34:41)` in my Ionic2 rc0 project. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome answer. :) Luckily I found this before start debugging.

Answer (score 2):

All these errors are related to AoT. This blog post explains the changes to be made in your code.

[Making your Angular 2 library statically analyzable for AoT](https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5#.m9oce43z9)

1. const lambda => export function
2. default export => named export
3. private, protected accessors should be changed to public for any members accessed from template
4. dynamic component template => static template
5. moduleId should be set on components with templateUrl